# Começar um projeto no Symfony2 com APIRest

Tags: api, symfony-2

Galera sou novo no symfony2 e tenho todo um projeto já em web funcionando que desenvolvi para aprender e ter um diferencial na hora de procurar um estagio, mas agora gostaria de começar a aprender a usar a parte da API entendi pelo guia de referencia, como funciona os controladores e rotas, e por outra pergunta que fiz, me indicaram o Postman do google, para testar as coisas que fosse desenvolvendo. Procurei alguns tutoriais e fora a maioria tar em inglês de indianos, o que complica porque não sou fluente em inglês, não encontrei nada que me explicasse passo a passo como começar.

Alguém tem algum material para me passar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desenvolver uma API em REST no Symfony2 não difere muito (em termos de organização do código) do desenvolvimento de um sistema web, por exemplo. Alguns paradigmas como autenticação e tipo de requisição/resposta, no entanto, são diferentes.

As principais bibliotecas que uso para desenvolver APIs em REST são:

- [`friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle`](https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle): para facilitar a configuração e desenvolvimento de uma API em REST com Symfony;
- [`jms/serializer-bundle`](https://packagist.org/packages/jms/serializer-bundle): para facilitar a serialização e desserialização de objetos em JSON ou XML;
- [`https://packagist.org/packages/nelmio/api-doc-bundle`](https://packagist.org/packages/nelmio/api-doc-bundle): para gerar uma documentação *on-the-fly* da sua API.

Dependendo das necessidades da sua aplicação, recomendo também essas bibliotecas:

- [`friendsofsymfony/user-bundle`](https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle): para facilitar o gerenciamento de usuários;
- [`friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle`](https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle): para configurar um servidor OAuth v2, por meio do qual credenciais de acesso podem ser trocados por pares de chave de (*access token* e *refresh token*), o que aumenta a confiabilidade da sua aplicação.

Como eu havia dito, o que muda principalmente é o esquema de autenticação e a forma como os dados serão lidos e escritos (em JSON ou em XML, e com o uso de verbos HTTP como `GET`, `PUT`, `POST` e `DELETE`).

Pela documentação do `FOSRestBundle`, você aprende a configurar seus controladores para enviar objetos serializados de acordo com a requisição do cliente. Pode-se enviar um único objeto, uma coleção de objetos, envelopados ou não – a escolha é sua. Além disso, pelo `JMSSerializerBundle`, você pode fazer um ajuste fino em que atributos de cada objeto serão serializados em cada rota. Por exemplo, em uma listagem de usuários você pode passar apenas o `id` e o `username` de cada um, mas na hora de pegar esse usuário você pode retornar todos os seus atributos.

Quanto à autenticação, obviamente você não terá um formulário de login e senha a fim de prover acesso aos recursos protegidos daquele usuário. Normalmente usa-se autorização básica (na qual as credenciais são passadas pelo cabeçalho `Authorization` da requisição usando o tipo `Basic`).

Entretanto esse tipo de autorização expõe as credenciais do cliente em todas as requisições, e pode-se optar por um esquema de autenticação um pouco mais parrudo – usando-se OAuth v2 ou outro protocolo de autenticação. Nesse protocolo você só passa as credenciais na primeira chamada, e usa chaves de acesso (que expiram de tempos em tempos) para as chamadas seguintes. A biblioteca `FOSOAuthServerBundle` ajuda a configurar um cliente OAuth, além de criar as tabelas e fornecer uma forma fácil de conectar esse tipo de autenticação às rotas de sua aplicação.

Enfim, essa é a forma que trabalho com APIs em REST. Se aparecer mais alguma dúvida ou precisar de ajuda na implementação de alguma das bibliotecas que citei acima, é só falar. :)